# Why HttpURLConnection.getHeaderFields() returns a list in reverse order?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

There's three "Set-Cookie" keys in response headers.

For instance:

```
Set-Cookie: JID=100; Path=/
Set-Cookie: PID=""; Path=/
Set-Cookie: JID=101; Path=/
```

I checked the "responses" property in HttpURLConnection and it had the right order.

However, when I called

```
getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"")
```

method, it returned a list in reverse order, which means that JID=100 is the newest Cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the JDK Bug System. It's an open unresolved bug.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133686